# namespace with submodule imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, python-import

I am wanting to use a simple list comprehension to set `__all__` for the modules in my package. I am noticing that when I import something from one of my own modules that the module name is added to the namespace, not just what I am importing. This is not the same when as when importing builtin or third-party packages.

```
- foo
  - __init__.py
  - bar.py
  - baz.py
```

`__init__.py`

```
import os as _os

from numpy.random import randint as _randint

import foo.bar as _bar

from foo.baz import foobar

__all__ = [x for x in globals() if not x.startswith('_')]
```

I expect:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.__all__
['foobar']
```

But I get:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.__all__
['bar', 'baz', 'foobar']
```

I know I could expand my list comprehension for `__all__` to filter out `ModuleType` but I am wondering why the behavior is different for my own modules. I would really like to be able to use a leading underscore to handle this as I can with other packages. I have also tried using `dir()`, `locals()`, and `vars()` instead of `globals()` but the result is the same.

**Update**
Out of curiosity, I also imported `foobar` into `bar.py` and printed `globals()` and `'bar'` was not included. So, it appears my modules are only added to the namespace within `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Keep in mind that submodules are inherently attributes of their parent modules. For example, ``concurrent.futures`` is literally the ``.futures`` attribute of ``concurrent``. In your case, ``foo`` contains ``baz`` because the latter is actually ``foo.baz``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credits to @MisterMiyagi in comments.

I will only confirm this with a quote from the official documentation [5.4.2. Submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism [...] **a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object**.

For example in your case, if package `foo` has a submodule `bar`, after importing `foo.bar`, `foo` will have an attribute `bar` which is bound to the submodule `foo.bar`.